# Server access Error while building Apache Spark 0.8.0

Tags: sbt, apache-spark

**UPDATE** : No idea how I ended up solving it, but it ended up working with 0.8.0. I think I just got the sources from an other repository which worked this time.

While executing `sbt/sbt assembly` to build Spark on my machine (I'm currently running Ubuntu on VirtualBox, but that shouldn't be the issue), I'm getting the following error:

```
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out url=https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-parent/20/jetty-parent-20.pom
```

It seems the above URL isn't working, and accessing it manually, even on other machines, doesn't work. Any ideas to get the file nonetheless ?

Here's the full console log if that helps somehow.

```
ulysse@ulysse-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/spark-0.8.0-incubating$ sbt/sbt assembly
[info] Loading project definition from /home/ulysse/Downloads/spark-0.8.0-incubating/project/project
Cloning into '/home/ulysse/.sbt/staging/90b1b0889ba1299e38f2'...
[info] Loading project definition from /home/ulysse/Downloads/spark-0.8.0-incubating/project
[info] Updating {git://github.com/ijuma/junit_xml_listener.git#fe434773255b451a38e8d889536ebc260f4225ce}default-052ce0...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_10_1;0.12.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/home/ulysse/Downloads/spark-0.8.0-incubating/project/}plugins...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_10_1;0.12.4 ...
[info] downloading http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/0.9.1/jars/sbt-assembly.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.9.1!sbt-assembly.jar (4422ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/2.2.0/jars/sbteclipse-plugin.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.2.0!sbteclipse-plugin.jar (2195ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/mpeltonen/sbt-idea_2.9.2_0.12/1.5.1/sbt-idea-1.5.1.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.5.1!sbt-idea.jar (4589ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/virtual-void/sbt-dependency-graph_2.9.2_0.12/0.7.3/sbt-dependency-graph-0.7.3.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] net.virtual-void#sbt-dependency-graph;0.7.3!sbt-dependency-graph.jar (2009ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-core/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/2.2.0/jars/sbteclipse-core.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-core;2.2.0!sbteclipse-core.jar (5483ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalaz/scalaz-core_2.9.2/6.0.4/scalaz-core_2.9.2-6.0.4.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scalaz#scalaz-core_2.9.2;6.0.4!scalaz-core_2.9.2.jar (28459ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/commons-io/commons-io/2.0.1/commons-io-2.0.1.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] commons-io#commons-io;2.0.1!commons-io.jar (1796ms)
[info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/mdr/ascii-graphs_2.9.2/0.0.2/ascii-graphs_2.9.2-0.0.2.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.github.mdr#ascii-graphs_2.9.2;0.0.2!ascii-graphs_2.9.2.jar (2180ms)
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/ulysse/.sbt/staging/90b1b0889ba1299e38f2/target/scala-2.9.2/sbt-0.12/classes...
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/ulysse/Downloads/spark-0.8.0-incubating/project/target/scala-2.9.2/sbt-0.12/classes...
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/home/ulysse/Downloads/spark-0.8.0-incubating/)
Getting Scala 2.9.3 ...
downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.9.3/scala-compiler-2.9.3.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.9.3!scala-compiler.jar (64928ms)
downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.9.3/scala-library-2.9.3.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.9.3!scala-library.jar (48661ms)
downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/jline/2.9.3/jline-2.9.3.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#jline;2.9.3!jline.jar (1021ms)
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
    confs: [default]
    4 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (20346kB/242ms)
[info] Updating {file:/home/ulysse/Downloads/spark-0.8.0-incubating/}core...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-server;7.6.8.v20121106 ...
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out url=https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/7.6.8.v20121106/jetty-server-7.6.8.v20121106.pom
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-project;7.6.8.v20121106 ...
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out url=https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-project/7.6.8.v20121106/jetty-project-7.6.8.v20121106.pom
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-parent;20 ...
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out url=https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-parent/20/jetty-parent-20.pom
```

Comment: Have you sorted it out? Does it work with the latest release 0.9.0?

Comment: No idea how I ended up solving it, but it ended up working with 0.8.0. I think I just got the sources from an other repository which worked this time.

Comment: Would you mind adding the comment as **UPDATE** at the beginning of your question? It appears there are going to be no answers to your question whatsoever since you sorted it out with no clue how.

Answer (score 2):

All of them seem to be available from Maven Central:

- http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/7.6.8.v20121106/
- http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-project/7.6.8.v20121106/
- http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-parent/20/

Maybe by creating a bogus project using those dependencies, sbt will pull them from Maven Central and Ivy might cache them.

Answer (score 1):

I also got this same error. Download the new version from this link and try again

http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-0.9.0-incubating.tgz

It took around 2 hour for me. If it fails, delete that folder and extract it again